# time data does not match

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, datetime

I have an issue where it says:

```
time data '2021-08-17 05:42:48 ' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

but my code is:

```
df['Event_Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Start_Time'], format='%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am not sure why the two formats are not matching

Comment: Because you're using forward-slashes in the formatting-string, instead of the `-` that is in your example! Also, change `%y`  to `%Y`. You can read more about [datetime formatting codes here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: For common formats like this, don't use `format` at all, just `pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Start_Time'])`.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by [Hampus Larsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8805293/hampus-larsson) in the comment, there are two typos in your code:

- format code for year is `%Y`, not `%y`
- in your dataframe years, months and days are separated with `-`, not `/`

In general, you can refer to [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the available date and time format codes.
That being said, you should use:

```
df['Event_Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Start_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're following my code example from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824990/) where I showed an example of reading in a string like `4/12/19 06:00`.  Setting the format with `/` in that case would work but you have to look at what you actually have.

Run `df.info()` and see if the column is actually datetime already.  If not look at the format you have and match it.   Probably `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` in your case.